# Sentinel 2 download not triggered

Tags: sentinel2, sentinelsat

I am trying to download sentinel 2 data from the Copernicus Open Access Hub, with a python script and using the [sentinelsat](https://sentinelsat.readthedocs.io/en/master/api_overview.html) library. I know that the rate at which you can download data is limited: max 2 concomitant downloads. However, I seem to have problems when I try to download a higher quantity of data (10-20 queries) one after the other in a *for* loop, therefore not in concomitance.
The command api.download(<product_id>) does not trigger the download, rather it just prints something like [This is the output I get rather than the actual download happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKO9O.png)